# Linking namespace to executable

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i have two executable i build them with:

```
 add_executable(MapProcessing src/MapProcessing.cpp BasicCalculation.cpp)
```

added minimal example

function header MapProcessing.h

```
#ifndef MAPPROCESSING_H_
#define MAPPROCESSING_H_

#include <BasicCalculation.h>

class MapProcessing
{
public:
    MapProcessing();
private:
    void DoSomething();
};

#endif /* MAPPROCESSING_H_ */
```

function cpp

```
#include "map_processing.h"

void MapProcessing::DoSomething(){
     Eigen::Vector2d vector(1,0);
    double test=BasicCalculation::test;
    int p=BasicCalculation::a();
    double test=BasicCalculation::AngleBetweenXaxisAndVector(vector);
  }
}
```

header namespace:

```
#ifndef BASICCALCULATION_H_
#define BASICCALCULATION_H_

#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/Eigenvalues>
#include <Eigen/Geometry>

namespace BasicCalculation{
  double AngleBetweenXaxisAndVector(const Eigen::Vector2d& vector);
  static double test=2;
  static int a(){return 1;}
};

#endif /* BASICCALCULATION_H_ */
```

cpp namespace

```
#include "BasicCalculation.h"
using namespace BasicCalculation;

double AngleBetweenXaxisAndVector(const Eigen::Vector2d& vector)
{
   calculate angle;
   return angle;
}
```

when i build this. I get an error

```
undefined reference to `BasicCalculation::AngleBetweenXaxisAndVector(Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1> const&)'
```

but variable test and function a() are working.

I have no idea why...

can u please help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72823/linking-namespace-to-executable/) by [Hunk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3946/hunk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 222 on 2013-08-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-08-14**:
The function named in the undefined reference error is not linked to your executable. Error sources are: You named it slightly different (including the function signature) or you did not compile+link the code that contains this. For more help you've gotta come up with a full minimal example.

**Comment by [Hunk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3946/hunk/) on 2013-08-14**:
ok I edited my full minimal example

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-08-14**:
I don't see where `namespace_one` is defined? What is in `namespace.h`?

**Comment by [Hunk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3946/hunk/) on 2013-08-14**:
sry namespace_one is my BasicCalculation i have added the full minimal example and delete namespace_one now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The function `double AngleBetweenXaxisAndVector(const Eigen::Vector2d& vector)` in your cpp is not defined in the namespace. The `using` directive does NOT do this. It does something else.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hunk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3946/hunk/) on 2013-08-14**:
shit i am an idiot

thank you